# Changing a value from an array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I'm trying to change the sexe value of a person when their name is mentioned. My function `changerSexe()` is the function created for this process. But i keep getting this `error.unexpected type` line 83 is in the function `changerSexe()` and is :`pers[i].getSexe()=sexe;`. It will not allow me to access the sexe and change it.

```
import java.util.*;
class Personne{
    private String nomPre;
    private double taille;
    private char sexe;
    private double poids;
    private int codePerm;

    public Personne(String nomPre,char sexe,double taille,double poids,int codePerm){
        this.nomPre=nomPre;
        this.taille=taille;
        this.sexe=sexe;
        this.poids=poids;
        this.codePerm=codePerm;
    }
    public Personne(){
    }
    public String getNomPre(){
        return nomPre;
    }
    public double getTaille(){
        return taille;
    }
    public char getSexe(){
        return sexe;
    }
    public double getPoids(){
        return poids;
    }
    public int getCodePerm(){
        return codePerm;
    }
    public String redNomPre(){
        return String.format("%s",getNomPre());
    }
    public String redTaille(){
        return String.format("%f",getTaille());
    }
    public String redSexe(){
        return String.format("%c",getSexe());
    }
    public String redPoids(){
        return String.format("%f",getPoids());
    }
    public String redCodePerm(){
        return String.format("%d",getCodePerm());
    }
    public char getSexe(char sexe){
        return sexe;
    }
}

public class numero2{
    static void afficher(Personne[]pers){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<pers.length;i++){
            System.out.printf("%s  %c  %f  %f  %d\n",pers[i].getNomPre(),pers[i].getSexe(),pers[i].getTaille(),pers[i].getPoids(),pers[i].getCodePerm());
            count++;
        }
        System.out.printf("Il y a %d de personne.\n",count);
    }

    static void afficherT(Personne[]pers){

        for(int i=0;i<pers.length;i++){
            System.out.printf("%s  %s  %s  %s  %s\n",pers[i].redNomPre(),pers[i].redSexe(),pers[i].redTaille(),pers[i].redPoids(),pers[i].redCodePerm());   
        }
    }


    static int search(Personne[]pers,String mot){

        for(int i=0;i<pers.length;i++){
            if(pers[i].getNomPre()==mot)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    static void changerSexe(Personne[]pers,char sexe,String nom ){
        for(int i=0;i<pers.length;i++){
            if(pers[i].getNomPre()==nom){
                pers[i].getSexe()=sexe;

            }               
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Personne[]pers={new Personne("ROY CHANTAL",'F',1.63,54.9,2759),new Personne("MOLAISON CLAUDE",'M',1.57,62.2,1848),
                        new Personne("BEDARD MARC-ANDRE",'M',1.43,80.5,2636),new Personne("MONAST STEPHANIE",'M',1.65,61.7,1750),
                        new Personne("JALBERT LYNE",'F',1.63,61.7,1750),new Personne("DUBE FRANCOISE",'F',1.68,67.5,4612),
                        new Personne("ROBITAILLE JACQUES",'M',1.72,65.4,2325),new Personne("LABELLE LISE",'F',1.79,68.0,1512),
                        new Personne("RIVERIN HELENE",'F',1.71,60.8,2340),new Personne("MICHAUD NORMAND",'M',1.73,103.7,3428),
                        new Personne("RICHER AGATHE",'F',1.65,53.1,3563),new Personne("BEGIN MARIE-LUCE",'F',1.62,49.0,4101),
                        new Personne("ROBITAILLE SUZANNE",'F',1.48,61.5,4371),new Personne("DUMITRU PIERRE",'M',1.92,99.4,3629),
                        new Personne("FILLION ERIC",'M',1.78,75.7,2630),new Personne("DESMARAIS DENISE",'F',1.75,58.7,3215),
                        new Personne("TREMBLAY MARC",'M',1.79,64.9,3529),new Personne("TREMBLAY SYLVIE",'M',1.83,86.2,1538),
                        new Personne("ROBITAILLE SUZANNE",'F',1.58,60.2,4119),new Personne("CHOQUETTE ALAIN",'M',1.78,70.3,5678),
                        new Personne("ROY HELENE",'F',1.62,61.7,4146)};
        System.out.println("1.Remplir le tableau pers et de compter puis retourner le nombre de personnes lues:");
        afficher(pers);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("2.Afficher le contenu du tableau pers en utilisant la redefinition de toString:");
        afficherT(pers);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Tremblay Sylvie est a l'index : "+search(pers,"TREMBLAY SYLVIE"));
        System.out.println("Robitaille Suzanne est a l'index : "+search(pers,"ROBITAILLE SUZANNE"));
        System.out.println("Tremblay Caroline est a l'index : "+search(pers,"TREMBLAY CAROLINE"));

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show where is line 83?

Comment: @KickButtowski: I'll bet `pers[i].getSexe()=sexe;`, which attempts assignment to rvalue. OP, you need to make a setter like `public void setSexe(char value)` on `Personne`, you can't do it the way you're doing.

Comment: @Amadan post up your answer plz so I can vote you and not sure if there are other issues as well

Comment: @KickButtowski: Just upvote xpa1492 instead :P There might be more errors, but this would be the one he asked about...

Comment: xpa's ways of doing fixed the error for me. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create "setters" for class members you want to write values to. In your case, you can add this to the class Personne:

```
public void setSexe(char sexe) {
    this.sexe = sexe;
}
```

Then instead of `pers[i].getSexe()=sexe`, use `pers[i].setSexe(sexe)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following will not work

```
pers[i].getSexe() = sexe;
```

compiler evaluate the rvalue of expresseion and put it in lvalue. But here you are trying to evaluate rvalue.

There is also a function in  `Personne`

```
public char getSexe(char sexe) {
    return sexe;
}
```

what was the purpose of this function. You have already defined a getter. 
just change it to a setter. like here :

```
public void setSexe(char sexe) {
    this.sexe = sexe;
}
```

Now you can use it in your `changerSexe(...)` function by replacing :

```
pers[i].getSexe() = sexe;
```

with this :

```
pers[i].setSexe(sexe);
```